# how to deploy the asp.net core application in azure Docker?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

I had developed a simple asp.net core application with Docker support in visual studio 2017 by following [developing Docker container-based applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/docker-application-development-process/docker-app-development-workflow#workflow-for-developing-docker-container-based-applications).

And also followed this [HOW TO DEVELOP MICROSERVICES USING .NET CORE & DOCKER](https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/develop-microservices-net-core-docker).

I run the asp.net application in my local Docker its working fine. But I don’t know how to deploy same application in azure Docker.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the question is rather vague and has lots of answers. In my opinión the most straightforward way of doing so is creating docker images and pushing them to the azure container registry. they can be pulled from there and used in Azure (or anywhere).

[Here's the basics on how to do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli).